# How to filter HTML elements based on the parent

Tags: html, css

I need to apply a function to checkbox elements that are not part of a bootstrap-multiselect element. To do this I'm trying to make a css selector that fitlers out based on the parent they have. The syntax that I have so far is this:

```
 $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']:not(ul.multiselect-container>input)")
```

Where the `:not(ul.multiselect-container>input)` is my attempt to specify to the css selector that I want all css elements except for the ones that are children of an unordered list that has the class multiselect-container.

From doing some investigation it seems that this should be possible, but my syntax doesn't seem to cut it. How can I make this work with the `:not` function? OR perhaps another way.

Comment: I'm assuming your inputs are inside <li> elements, so try removing **>** like so : :not(ul.multiselect-container input)

Comment: In this case, what i can suggest is, Select all checkbox and then try to remove/hide ul.multslect-container input as you have id for those so it will be easy to remove then to filter. Right?